# Jquery Mobile makes script execute twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

why does the `test` message shows twice on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Test");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I copied the headers from from http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/getting-started.html  and as I started doing some examples I noticed that my javascript methods where being called twice.

Here is the code in JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LsxBW/2/

Comment: Does it fire once if you enclose it in $(function(){});

Comment: Good question. if I enclose it as `$(function(){ alert("Test"); });` It also fires twice why?

Comment: You have to play by jQuery mobile's rules: http://jsfiddle.net/LsxBW/

Comment: Curious. Can you make a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/LsxBW/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Explosion Pills perfectly stated **you have to play by jQM rules**. At least:

- Use appropriate [jQM markup](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html) for a page or pages

```html
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">    
        <p>Page content goes here.</p>        
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

- [Use `pageinit` event instead of jQuery ready handler](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html).
  So instead of

```js
$(function() {   
    alert("Test");
});
```

use

```js
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(){
    alert("Test");
});
```

[jsFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/YrRgp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(function() {   
    alert("Test");
});
```

.. just fine, as long as you put it outside of the div with data-role="page".
No script tags allowed inside the page markup.